# Is there a way to decltype the result of a non callable function?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I would like to know if anyone has same trick to find the return type of the `find_me` function, without changing it's argument.

```
struct Stuck {
    Stuck() = delete;
    Stuck(Stuck&&) = delete;
    Stuck(const Stuck&) = delete;
    Stuck& operator=(Stuck&&) = delete;
    Stuck& operator=(const Stuck&) = delete;
};

double find_me(Stuck);

int main() {
    // This obviously don't work
    decltype(find_me(Stuck{})) test1;
}
```

This is another shot I tried:

```
template<typename T>
struct ConvertTo {
    operator T ();
}

int main() {
    decltype(find_me(ConvertTo<Stuck>{})) test1;
}
```

The function `find_me` is overloaded many many times, and never actually implemented. I just want to know if there's a way to find the return type when the function has these form. I know that it would be possible to receive a pointer or a reference, this is what I'm already doing, but I would like to know if there also some trick to make this work.

If there is any, please tell me, and tell me why.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's overloaded, no.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. I'll keep using a reference then.

Comment: What purpose could this `find_me` function possibly have, regardless of whether it's by-value or by-reference?

Comment: @Brian I only use it to get the return type. The function is actually never implemented.

Comment: Yes but even if you are only using it in a metaprogramming context, why would you go out of your way to make the argument type impossible to construct?

Comment: @Brian I'm not in control of the types. Users of my code will provide a type accompanied by a `find_me` to map it's type to some other type.

Comment: That's a really weird API.

Comment: hmm, works for me on clang's trunk - https://godbolt.org/g/zTnyvZ

Comment: @T.C. It used to be weirder. [See for yourself](https://github.com/gracicot/kangaru/wiki/04.-Invoke). The old syntax used specialization, which is quite uglier.

Comment: @Kobi That's C++17 "guaranteed elision" coupled with the fact that `Stuck` is an aggregate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
struct Stuck {
    Stuck() = delete;
    Stuck(Stuck&&) = delete;
    Stuck(const Stuck&) = delete;
    Stuck& operator=(Stuck&&) = delete;
    Stuck& operator=(const Stuck&) = delete;
};

double find_me(Stuck);
void find_me(double);

template <typename Ret>
Ret get_stuck_return_type(Ret (*)(Stuck));

int main() {
    decltype(get_stuck_return_type(find_me)) test1;
}
```

Coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eca81a13fae9de3

The reason why this works even when `find_me` is overloaded is that the template argument deduction will try each overload of `find_me`. If deduction succeeds with exactly one overload, that one is chosen for instantiating the template.

I assume this is a purely academic exercise, since a function taking an unconstructible type by value could serve no actual purpose.

Comment: Yes that function will have a purpose. I use it to map some type to another. The function is never implemented. I use it in a metaprogramming context.

Comment: Doesn't work if any `find_me` is a template. `template<class T>
void find_me(double, T);` will kill it.

Comment: @T.C. I agree, I don't think there is a general solution to this problem. OP really ought to rethink his design goals.

Comment: @Brian actually, I'll continue using const references as parameters. I was just curious about it :)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot a pointer would work too... `(T*)0` is very easy to type

Comment: Suggestion: `template <typename...Args, typename Ret> Ret get_stuck_return_type(Ret(Args...));`. If the OP has many overloaded `find_me` functions, it seems reasonable to provide a single interface to find them all (so `decltype(get_stuck_return_type<Stuck>(find_me))` is `double`, and `decltype(get_stuck_return_type<double>(find_me))` is `void`)

Answer (score 0):

[std::declval](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) does the trick:

```
decltype(find_me(std::declval<Stuck>())) test1;
```

Comment: `use of deleted function 'Stuck::Stuck(Stuck&&)'`

Answer (score 0):

What about making the user add template specializations?

Your code:

```
template <typename T>
struct find_me
{
    struct please_add_your_own_find_me {};
    using type = please_add_your_own_find_me;
};
```

Client code:

```
template <>
struct find_me<Stuck>
{
    using type = double;
};
```

Then:

```
find_me<Stuck>::value test1;
```